# Pycharm cannot import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

My system is Mac OS X.
I first installed numpy through macport and then download Pycharm and find that whatever interpreter I choose I cannot import numpy. The results are as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 "/Users/erleye/Documents/Python/Pycharm Projects/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erleye/Documents/Python/Pycharm Projects/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But if I use `python test.py` in the terminal it works fine.
When I type `which -a python` in terminal, i have:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I don't know why I have so many versions of python, but I am sure when I chose interpreter in Pycharm, it is the one that has numpy installed.
What can I do?

Comment: Are any of these versions Python 3? Try `python --version` from the terminal. It's possible numpy is installed for Python 3, but not Python 2.

Comment: Well, you have 3 versions of Python, not 6; you've somehow added `/opt/local/bin` to your `PATH` 3 times instead of just once, and `/usr/local/bin/python` is almost certainly a link to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`, which is probably a python.org binary install.

Comment: Meanwhile, the one you're running in PyCharm is the `/Library` one (as you can tell from the error message). How are you sure that's the one you installed numpy for, when you don't even know how that one got there in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why I have so many versions of python, but I am sure when I chose interpreter in Pycharm, it is the one that has numpy installed.

No it isn't.

According to your `which`, the Python that gets run when you type `python python.py` at the terminal is going to be `/opt/local/bin/python`, the MacPorts one.

But according to the error message in PyCharm, the Python that it's running is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`, which is not the MacPorts one. (It's probably from a binary installer from Python.org.)

So, that's your problem.

Well, it's just barely possible that you're running the MacPorts Python, but you've somehow set a `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` to force it to try to use the Python.org site-packages instead of its own. But in that case, you've got even bigger problems…

Of course your bigger problem is that you have 3 different copies of Python 2.7, and a total of 6 path entires for them, and you don't even know how you got them or which ones' site-packages you're installing into. It would probably be easier to clean things up than to keep trying to muddle through, but it's your choice.

Comment: Yes, I have found the problem. It is exactly what you said. When I start the project I used the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7. Even after I changed the interpreter in configuration to a new one, it still used the site-packages of the old python. Problem gets fixed after I start a new project using the new interpreter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But I am just confused which python shall I clean.

Comment: @Erle: Well, why did you install two extra Python 2.7's, on top of the one Apple gave you, in the first place? Maybe you need one of them—but if so, you should be able to explain why, and that explanation should tell you which one you need. So scrap the one you don't need. (Or both, if you don't need either.)

Comment: @Erle: And if you need another Python 2.7 besides Apple's, make sure never to install anything into Apple's Python's site-packages (and if you have installed anything into it, you may want to clean that up too); that's the only way you're going to avoid confusing yourself.